# Event after sound totally played?

Tags: events, audio

This is my simplified code:

```
function PreloadSounds()
{
    createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", eSoundLoad);
    createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["mp3"];
    createjs.Sound.registerSound({id:"knock",src:sndurl+"knock.mp3"});
}

function eSoundLoad(event) {
    sndKnock = createjs.Sound.createInstance(event.src);
}
```

I would like to know if there is any event that is fired after a sound is totally played...

Thanks!